# Query Optimizer choosing non-filtered index instead of filtered

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I want to create a index for this query:

```
SELECT TOP (100)
    HORA_LEIT
FROM
    DADOS
WHERE
    COD_PONTO = 610
    AND HORA_LEIT <= '2022-09-29 12:25:00.000'
    AND VAZAO IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    HORA_LEIT DESC
```

Through my research, I figured out the existence of filtered indexes, so my first try was to create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_cod_ponto_hora_leit 
ON DADOS (cod_ponto, hora_leit) 
INCLUDE (vazao) 
WHERE VAZAO IS NOT NULL
```

But when I run it, SQL Server decided to use this index instead:

```
INDEX IX_cod_ponto_hora_leit_St_bomba 
ON DADOS (cod_ponto, hora_leit, St_bomba) 
INCLUDE (vazao)
```

I thought in this case the query optimizer would choose the filtered one.

Am I using filtered index wrong?

Is it enough to have an index like?

```
CREATE INDEX IX_cod_ponto_hora_leit 
ON DADOS (cod_ponto, hora_leit) 
INCLUDE (vazao)
```

Comment: What happens if you use a _normal_ index (`CREATE INDEX IX_cod_ponto_hora_leit ON DADOS ( cod_ponto, hora_leit ) INCLUDE ( vazao )`) - your post doesn't say.

Comment: Please post a **real** query that shows us what you actually have instead of `X` and `Y` because that impacts how SQL Server chooses an index.

Comment: @Dai  If it is using well an index on cod_ponto_hora_leit_St_bomba I don't need to create this one. The point is that I thought it would prefer to use the filtered index...

Comment: Please share the actual execution plan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @Dai Filtered - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1fmM2Vzj

Non-filtered - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByOKb34Mj

Comment: You need to specify descending sort order: `CREATE INDEX IX_cod_ponto_hora_leit
ON DADOS (cod_ponto, hora_leit DESC) 
INCLUDE (vazao) WHERE VAZAO IS NOT NULL`